# Invoking external commands with options from a makefile

Tags: command-line, makefile, echo, arduino

I have a [makefile for compiling Arduino programs](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/).

I need to add some text at the beginning of some files based on some logic. I am using *echo* command for that.

```
ECHO    = echo
```

and later in the file, I have lot of places like

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.cpp: %.pde
    $(ECHO) '#if ARDUINO >= 100\n    #include "Arduino.h"\n#else\n    #include "WProgram.h"\n#endif' > $@
```

which works fine.

Recently, some users complained that echo command doesn't work properly in some linux distros and I had to add the '-e' option to the echo command.

So I changed the first line where I declare the command to

```
ECHO    = echo -e
```

This is not working, because makefile considers -e as part of the text and not as part of the option.

**Edit**:

I am not getting any error, but the text -e is also appended to the file that I am creating.

Is there a way to declare the -e as an option and not as part of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you're seeing behavior differences because `echo` is a shell built-in command in some versions of some shells.  Then that's being compounded because make only sometimes uses the shell to invoke commands -- it will prefer to invoke commands directly if possible.  So, sometimes, on some systems, you are not invoking the `echo` command that you think you are.

You would probably have better luck by setting

```
ECHO = /bin/echo -e
```

which will explicitly invoke the external `echo` command, even if the shell has a built-in version.  That way you should get consistent results.

Comment: Thanks this solved it. But I am not sure, whether this will have any issue with Mac OS. Need to test it there as well.

Answer (score 1):

if get `/bin/sh: 1: -e: not found` error it's related to your shell, not makefile.else, please put your error. of course if you get error.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am not getting any error, but the text -e is also getting appended to the file, that I am creating.

Comment: @Sudar i found the following text from man page of echo: , this is not your problem **your  shell  may  have its own version of echo, which usually supersedes the version described  here.  Please refer to your shell's documentation for details about the options it supports.**